# AWS BeanStalk deployment failed in .net?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi there i tried upload and deployed a sample web service in AWS beanstalk environment as guided in tutorial,
But when i try to deploy my own web service following error occurred :
 
**Deployment of the website failed due to errors during build of the deployment archive,
 check visual studio output window 'Build' and/ or 'Amazon Web Service' panes for more details.** 
i couldn't get a solution why and how the error appeared i tried changing start page and tried to deploy multiple times but no use,
The web service i have is with Database, without importing database i can run it locally but while deploying to beanstalk the error occurred and failed.
Can anybody help me with this.
 
**Note : no error in output windows build successful = 0 failed = 0.**
Thank you.

Comment: Snapshot your logs and take a look in there...

Comment: Which log there is no logs created in logs or output console "successful =0, failed =0" actually what is amazon web service pane?

Comment: Do you have the AWS Explorer in VS? Open Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, then your application and double click on the environment. You should see a log there.

Comment: Yeah but that is generated only while publishing started, the error occurs before starting publish

Comment: In that case you can also look in the AWS Toolkit for VS logs which live in C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\logs

Comment: Ok thank you very much i am done it was visual studio error obviously i tried in 2012 it worked deployed thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, I opened up the log file at C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\logs

If you run the lengthy msdeploy.exe command at the bottom, you may find the error.  In my case it was trying to deploy to a folder that didn't exist in my temp directory:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\AWSDeploymentArchive_PROJECTNAME\

I created this folder manually and it seems to be working :)